# Android application disconnecting from server after first command.

Tags: java, android

I have developed both a server application on a PC to which an android application connects to and returns some values.
Both of them work well but the problem is that after I issue a command, the application stops sending anything to the server and I have to reconnect.
I figured a while clause would fix the problem but I have no idea where to put it.

**- This is my MainActivity Class**

```
package com.example.homepageunu;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    AlertDialog ad;
    public static String exportTxtbox;
    private Editable ip_name;
    private static String ip;
    public static String SERVERIP; //= "192.168.0.103"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 2003;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
        EditText txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_IP);     
        ip_name =  txt_name.getEditableText();
        SERVERIP = ip_name.toString();

        new Thread(new connectTask()).start();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    public class connectTask implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {       
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(SERVERIP,SERVERPORT);
            mTcpClient.startComm();
        }
    }

}
```

**- This is my TCPclient class**

```
package com.example.homepageunu;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class TCPClient {


    public static  String SERVERIP; 
    public static  int SERVERPORT ; 
    private boolean bRunning; 


    public Socket mSocket ;
    public static PrintWriter out;

    public static final byte DATA  = (byte) 254;        
    public static final byte COMMAND = (byte) 253;
    public static final byte C_GET_HOST_RESOLUTION  = 10;   
    public static final byte DATA_LENGTH = 10;


    private static byte[] outbuff = new byte[DATA_LENGTH] ;
    private static byte[] intbuff = new byte[DATA_LENGTH] ;


    public TCPClient(String szServerip, int uiServerPort) 
    {
        //Save desired ip and port 
        SERVERIP = szServerip;
        SERVERPORT = uiServerPort;
        bRunning = false;
    }



    public boolean startComm() 
    {
        try
        {           
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            mSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 2003);         
            bRunning = true;

            this.out = new PrintWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            return false;
        }
        finally 
        {

        }           
    }

    public boolean sendBytes(byte[] aub_BytesToSend)
    {
        if(bRunning)
        {
            try
            {

                OutputStream mOutStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream mInstream = mSocket.getInputStream();


                mOutStream.write(aub_BytesToSend);  
                mInstream.read(intbuff, 0, DATA_LENGTH);
                Log.i("TCP", Arrays.toString(intbuff));
                return true;


            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void waitForResponse()
    {

    }


    public interface OnMessageReceived 
    {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

**- This is my DisplayMessageActivity class**

```
package com.example.homepageunu;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
     public void modifyVolume(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, VolumeSetup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     /*1*/   public void SetPlay(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("1");
     }
     /*2*/   public void SetForward(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("2");
     }
     /*3*/   public void SetBackward(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("3");
     }
     /*4*/   public void SetStartup(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("4");
     }
     /*5*/   public void SetVolUp(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("5");
     }
     /*6*/   public void SetVolDown(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("6");
     }
     /*7*/   public void SetMute(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("7");
     }
     /*1*/   public void SetStop(View view)
     {
         TCPClient.out.println("0");
     }

}
```

**- This is my IpActivity class**

```
package com.example.homepageunu;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class IpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ip);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ip, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ip, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```